# Trying to understand Axler's proof that every linear operator has an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The proof is pictured in its entirety [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655634/question-about-axlers-proof-that-every-linear-operator-has-an-eigenvalue). So in general, I think I understand the point of the proof and some of the steps, but I seem to have a gap in my understanding. It's at the very end where he says "which means that T - λjI is injective for at least one j" that I get confused. How is it that we know it's injective, and why exactly does that imply there must be an eigenvalue?

Comment: Is not injective for for a least one $j$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read your linked page a little more carefully.  Axler says, "$T - \lambda_j I$ is ***not*** injective for at least one $j$. . . .

The product of injective operators is injective.  Thus if

$\prod_1^m (T - \lambda_j I) \tag{1}$

is not injective, at least one of the factors fails to be injective as well.